# arm_navigation generation always in collision for Robonaut?

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run the Robonaut2 URDF through the arm_navigation generation tutorial, but it looks like the end-effector is always in collision, and thus i can not generate plans using the planning_components_visualizer.

This is my guess of what's happening based on the end-effector being red upon start up:

[image: image description]

and complete inactivity when telling it to "plan" from the menu.

I am using the nasa_r2_common\r2_description\robots\r2c_full_body.urdf.xacro URDF, and choosing the left leg as the 'manipulator' though this seems to work regardless of which of the four limbs i choose.

Is there something i need to check/verify in the advanced wizard to make sure my description is valid?

FYI, I was hoping to push through with the warehouse and motion planning stacks, once I get this working....

Thanks,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43000/arm_navigation-generation-always-in-collision-for-robonaut?/) by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started looking at just the R2 upper body because I had this working with the arm_navigation some months ago, but have been running into similar issues as I have been with the legs.

Just to minimize the chances of collisions, I reduced all the collision models in the entire robot to about 80%, and unchecked all pairs in the advanced mode of the arm nav wizard.

Tabling for now the fact that if i chose more than one kinematic chain, the warehouse viewer wouldn't start properly for me, I'm still getting collisions for all possible movements.  The following picture shows what happens as soon as I move the marker (with the robot visualization at a lower alpha).  You can see the smaller collision models, none of which are in contact with each other, show up immediately as red (i.e. in collision). This is true for both arms, even when the (only) kinematic chain I have built the models for are between the chest and the left index finger base!

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) with karma: 86 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) on 2012-09-13**:
interestingly, when i remove the collision models for the hands and the first shoulder link, rviz shows the visual models as the collision models when i start up the warehouse viewer.  that cant be right....